# Android MediaCodec: video file processing: add the original audio, while process video

Tags: android, audio, android-mediacodec

The input is a video file.
I want to process each video frame, while the audio remains the same.
The output is a video file.

I basically follow the example DecodeEditEncodeTest.java and MeidaMuxerText.java in bigflake.com
Without adding audio track, the application works well.
Now I add audio track into the mMuxer.

Since I do not need to process the audio, I do not use decode or encode for the audio.

Here is a dilemma.
If I want to know whether the sample data is video or audio, I will use:
int chunkSize = extractor.readSampleData(inputBuf, 0)

If I set the inputBuf as a general ByteBuffer, and if the sample turns out to be audio, it is fine.
I just use mMuxer.writeSampleData to write the inputBuf to the output video file.

But if the sample turns out to be video, then I am supposed to write the data in the decoder's input buffer. But now since I do not know it first, how can I determine which buffer to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MediaExtractor.getSampleTrackIndex()` tells you which track the current sample comes from.

Comment: I thought getSampleTrackIndex() is reading the track of the current sample, so we need to first use getSampleTrackIndex(). But if we use getSampleTrackIndex(), we need to set the dataBuffer; and if we need to set dataBuffer, we need to know what format (video or audio) it is.

Comment: The "current sample" is not the sample that you just read, but the sample at the current position in the extractor. In other words, you can call getSampleTrackIndex() to find out which track you're going to read the next sample from, then call readSampleData() to read that sample into the appropriate buffer, then call advance() to move on to the next sample.